# To become (a) soloist

Tags: indefinite-articles

Should I put indefinite article in the sentence *She became (a) soloist of/with the American Ballet Theatre*?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say *She became **a** soloist **at** the American Ballet Theatre*.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the condition and number of positions.

If the American ballet theater has only one "soloist" position, then you should say "She became the soloist of the American ballet theater."

If the theater has many positions as a soloist, and she was given one of those positions, then you should say "She became a soloist at the American ballet theater."

Comment: But if it were a position where there was obviously only one incumbent at any one time it would be perfectly normal to drop the article altogether. 'Steve Gerrard is captain of the England football team'; 'Sir Simon Rattle is principal conductor of the Berlin Philharmonic Orchestra'.

Comment: Sure. You're right.